# How can i build my class without conflict between QSqlTableModel and Q_OBJECT?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to build next code, but compiler says:

> "sqltablemodel.h:12: error: undefined reference to `vtable for
>   SqlTableModel'"

I understand that the QSqlTableModel already has Q_OBJECT before.

But after removing this macro, I can't call my function from QML.

The debugger says that: *ajax is not a function.*

How can i build my class without conflict between inheritance & macros?

```
 //sqltablemodel.h
class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel {
       Q_OBJECT
    public:    
       Q_INVOKABLE void ajax(){
           qDebug() << "123";
       }
    }

    //main.cpp
     SqlTableModel *sqlTableModel =  new SqlTableModel();
        context->setContextProperty("sqlTableModel", sqlTableModel);
```

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` is not some class member that you can derive. It's instruction for `moc` to generate additional class members for the _specified_ class and to enable the meta object system. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) for more info. As for the `vtable` error - you probably have to run qmake and rebuild the project after adding the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, When using Qt Creator:

Build → Run qmake

Build → Rebuild All